# PostgreSQL : Question about dropping tables inside funtions

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am writing some PostgreSQL code where I have a function which is used multiple times in a single query with different input values. Inside the function I create some tables and use them.

What is the correct way to handle those tables? should I drop them at the end of the function (right before the RETURN), or should I use temp tables?